# DRIVER.findElements возвращает null

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Пытаюсь найти элемент на странице, но я получаю `null`. Проверил при помощи JQuery - всё норм.

Код:

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.phantomjs();
caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, PATH);
WebDriver DRIVER = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
DRIVER.get(URL);
List<WebElement> ELNTS = DRIVER.findElements(By.cssSelector("li.result"));
```

Почему так может быть?

Comment: Если элемент не виден на экране, так и будет. Невидимые элементы надо скроллить в область видимости, тогда Selenium их найдет.

Comment: Необходимо приложить html код.

Comment: @ЮрийБезруков html код - https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?facetNetwork=%5B%22F%22%2C%22S%22%5D&origin=FACETED_SEARCH&page=2

Comment: @KAGGDesign подскажешь как это сделать?

Comment: Посмотрел свой старый код на java. Ошибся я с комментарием. Элемент будет найден всегда, вот только кликнуть на него или присвоить ему значение (если это input) нельзя, если он вне экрана. Перед взаимодействием надо скроллить. Делается так: `    private static void scrollIntoView(ChromeDriver driver, WebElement element) {
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(false);", element);
    }
`

Comment: а у тебя элемент должен быть найден по идее. сам драйвер-то нормально инициировался?

Comment: @KAGGDesign Ну я использую phantomjs. Ошибок нет. Я понял в чём была проблема. Я выше кидал ссылку куда я захожу и чтобы туда попасть нужна авторизация.

Comment: а разницы нет, какой из драйверов selenium.

Comment: @KAGGDesign возникла проблема. не пойму. Захожу сюда: 
https://www.linkedin.com/m/login/ Тут есть форма авторизации - form. Но selenium в тупую не может найти. Даже js скрипт не помог. вообще без понятия. Открываю в хром окне.

Comment: а это popup, а попапы там по-другому надо искать. Я уже не помню, погугли.

Comment: @KAGGDesign для переключения на новую вкладку браузера\ всплывающее окно (не алерт) необходимо переключить windowHandle драйвера. Аналогично после исчезновения попапа, закрытия вкладки.  По моему ты все-таки ошибаешься насчет того, что нельзя ввести текст в поле или нажать на элемент если он за пределами окна. Никогда не пользовался скролом в селениуме, т.к. в этом нет необходимости. У нас селениум автоматом скролит в таких случаях. Как вариант можешь попробовать через action.sendKeys(PAGE_DOWN).perform();

Comment: @sky49rus если бы я на эти грабли не наступал со скроллом, у меня бы в коде не был этот скролл на каждый чих. А он есть. По крайней мере, в ChromeDriver

Comment: @KAGGDesign возможно особенности вашего фреймворка (либо версии standalone сервера). У нас в любом браузере (ff, chrome, ie, safari) скрол не требовался, за исключением случая, когда надо было проверять фильтры и кол-во подгружаемых изначально и по мере скрола результатов.

Comment: @Tsyklop поделись ссылкой на страницу, если есть такая возможность